# TornadoFX get reference to a tab and get its Stage

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

How can I get a reference to the first tab? And furthermore how do I get its Stage?

```
class MainApp : App() {
    override val primaryView = MainView::class

    class MainView : View() {
        override val root = VBox()

        init {
            with(root) {
                tabpane {
                    tab("Report") {
                        hbox {
                            // TODO Want a reference to this tab here.
                            // Ideally something like tab.getStage()
                            this += Button("Hello 1")
                        }
                    }
                    tab("Data Entry") {
                        hbox {
                            this += Button("Hello 2")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly: I've seen a lot of your posts here and they're pretty basic questions. These are things you could figure out on your own if you did your own digging. I'd recommend **at least** looking at the [official guide](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/) to get a good grasp on most of what you need to know. Then, check out other posts on here to see if they've been answered already.

But to answer your question:

```
class MainView : View() {
    override val root = vbox {
        tabpane {
            tab("Report") {
                hbox {
                    val tab = this@tab //Here is your tab
                    button("Hello 1")
                }
            }
            tab("Data Entry") {
                hbox {
                    button("Hello 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, I would urge you to look at the guide, as you missed some helpful building tools (see how I built the buttons? see how I moved the root out of init?). I'd hate for you to code more than you need to then realize you could've done less work if you had known how.

Also: Tabs don't have references to stages. They just inherit Styleable and EventTarget, they're not like Views or Fragments.

Comment: There is very little documentation or examples on TornadoFX to the point its more worthwhile to just use JavaFX. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Have you looked at the official guide? I've worked with TornadoFX for over 6 months and I can say it's worth it to learn it. JavaFX by itself is very verbose.

Comment: The way the tab is accessed is actually a language feature of Kotlin, not a specific TornadoFX mechanism. To be effective with TornadoFX it's very helpful to get a good grasp of Kotlin as well :)